# Implicit Cast Warning

Tags: apache-pig

When I run my pig script, I have a lot of

```
Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_LONG ... time(s).
Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_FLOAT ... time(s).
Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_DOUBLE ... time(s).
```

I was wondering under what circumstance PigServer will emit these warnings and whether these implicit castings will slow down the process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get the warnings when Pig has to implicitly cast from one type to another, for instance when you pass a field as an argument to a function that requires some type but the field is another type.

AFAIK implicit casts aren't slowing down the process more than explicit casts (i.e. (long)field1) - you get warnings because you should know that you're casting implicitly - you can't cast any type to any other type, and casts always cost, so you should try to eliminate data type casting as much as you can.